# PHP7 Null Coalescing or if/then shorthand -- Evaluate rather than return

Tags: php, conditional-statements, php-7, conditional-operator, shorthand

For a long time I have wanted to be able to do this without the slight extra cruft:

```
$test = 'test';
echo !empty($test2) ? 'something before ' . $test2 : '';
```

That will return an empty string, because `$test2` is not defined.

```
$test = 'test';
$test2 = 'test2';

echo !empty($test2) ? 'something before ' . $test2 : '';
```

This returns `"Something before test2"` when `$test2` is defined.

It doesn't matter if `: '';` is changed to `: false;` or `: null;` because here they will all evaluate to an empty string. So that's really been the thing. How come it's not possible to do `if/then`, and only `if/then/else`?

With PHP7's null coalescing double question mark `??` operator, it starts to seems like it gets closer to being able to do it. But I don't think that this operator actually does the trick.

```
$test = 'test';
$test2 = 'test2';

echo $test2 ?? 'test3';
```

We have "if `$test2` is not `null`, then just return it right away." So we aren't able to add "`Something before`" to it.

The ternary operator `?:` has a similar similar issue where this scenario is impossible because it returns a truthy value immediately. I don't so much mind the `!empty()` since it makes sense why it's necessary, but always tacking on the `: '';` seems kinda crufty for a common pattern...

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/PHP/comments/98rz1j/shorthand_comparisons_in_php_now_also_looking_at/e4im7eu/

Comment: But, what is the actual question?

Comment: @Furgas , in order to use a variable, it has to be set.. so we typically check that with `!empty()`... It would solve a lot of common cases to be able to test that condition, and if it is met, use the variable (either echo or assign).. So given that we just have to test the variable first to try and use it, oftentimes we don't need that `else` case... And there doesn't seem to be a way around it :( Nice links though!

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible, use the `&&` operator.

```
$test = 'test';
$test2 = 'test2';

!empty($test2) && ($test2 = 'something before ' . $test2);
```

The second half of the line will only execute if the first half resolves true.

**EDIT**

It should be noted that this is probably bad practice, as it could make it a little harder to read, but it works.

**EDIT 2**

My bad, this would only work if the second half can be resolved as a boolean, hence wouldn't work for an echo, but would work for an assignment.

Comment: I tested this and it seems to choke on the echo, `syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO)` ... But I can see where you're going with this, I'm not sure exactly why it won't parse... Here's a demo, just click Execute Code: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f7e8b91f5e67ef8a03c38fe6ae535acb483f7588 .. Thank you for contributing to ideas though! I think that for assignment it could be readable enough, but I can see what you mean.. Seems like it could be more readable than `echo !empty($test2) ? 'something before ' . $test2 : '';` which I think is fairly common

Comment: This would parse: `if (!empty($test2)) echo 'something before ' . $test2;`, but it doesn't solve the case of assignment because we can't do something like `$test3 = if (!empty($test2)) 'something before ' . $test2;`